# Translating imperative memoization code to Haskell

Tags: haskell, memoization

Memoization is a useful thing and since it's heavily related to functions, I'd assume Haskell has the right machinery to implement it in an at least fairly straightforward manner.

```
var memo = function (f) {
    var cache = {};
    return function (x) {
        if (cache[x]) return cache[x];
        else return cache[x] = f(x);
    }
}

//Usage:
var fib = memo(function (x) {
    if (x == 0) return 1;
    if (x == 1) return 1;
    return fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
});

fib(100);
```

This is the code I wrote in JavaScript that does what I want. What would be a good translation to Haskell that can offer similar practicality AND performance?

To reduce ambiguity of the question, I'm not interested in replicating the generality of the JS solution because Haskell is strongly typed. Something with a type signature of

```
memo :: (Int -> b) -> (Int -> b)
```

that can be manually extended for multiple parameters and maybe even various types would be fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main important thing the JavaScript solution hinges on is a fast-access mutable container; those languages generally implement them as hashmaps and make them a central language component (mainly because more sophisticated, specialised data structures can't be expressed in the feeble type system).

But not in Haskell. There are [hash-maps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) in libraries allright, but there's also containers *specifically designed for memoisation*: [memo-tries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie). Why not use those?

You can of course also hack your way without efficient container structures. The simplest way to memoise an `Int ->` function would be to store an infinite list of all results:

```
memoInt :: (Int -> b) -> Int -> b
memoInt f = look
 where positives = [ f x | x <- [0..] ]
       negatives = [ f x | x <- [-1, -2 ..] ]
       look x | x<0        = negatives !! (1-x)
              | otherwise  = positives !! x
```

Obviously, the list-lookups become very expensive for large `|x|`.

For a somewhat weird, but very easy way to make this reasonably fast, namely *O* (√*n*) instead of *O* (*n*):

```
memoInt' :: (Int -> b) -> Int -> b
memoInt' f = look
 where table = [ [ f (sqrtX^2 + dx) | dx <- [0..]    ]
                                    | sqrtX <- [0..] ]
       look x | x<0        = negDomain x
              | otherwise  = let sqrtX = floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral x
                             in table !! sqrtX !! (max 0 $ x - sqrtX)
       negDomain = memoInt' (f . negate)
```

(This might break for large numbers because of floating-point trouble, it's not really safe use of `sqrt`)

Comment: I can't complain about this answer since it is a correct one, but I'm not really happy with what it is. I have a choice of using a very expensive implementation that I can understand or use a fast one that someone else implemented for me and that I couldn't understand myself. Leaves a bad feeling.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if I could just swap out the infinite list for an infinite lazy map?

Comment: +1 for memo-tries. I was going to invent what turns out to be the HasTrie instance for Integer to answer this.

Comment: @LukaHorvat `Data.Map` isn't intended for infinite collections. Again, memo tries _are_ intended for this, so do use them! I can't really see why you shouldn't understand that yourself, just browse through the library code. It's definitely easier than understanding JavaScripts hash maps, which you'd need to _fully understand_ your original code.

Comment: @Luke, the "infinite lazy map" needs to know what the structure of the map is ahead of time, since it can't be changed by side effect as the code is evaluated. That means the structure of the map must depend solely on the structure of the datatype that is the key, and not on which values of the key have been populated.

Comment: @Cirdec I understand that but Haskell still compiles to imperative code. Infinite lists aren't infinite to the machine. They're just infinite for all intents and purposes to the one writing the code. I though that maybe there existed some abstraction that would also let me work with maps and "pretend" they're infinite when in fact the compiler reshapes them when needed.

Comment: @LukaHorvat: no, infinite lists are, in fact, infinite to the machine, in the same way that unbounded loops in an imperative language are infinite.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm sure there's reallocation of memory happening all the time as you access more members of the list, or at least allocation. The point is that the underlying structure does change. It's just abstracted away.

Comment: Well, there's sure allocation happening, but not reallocation (at least not usually, with lists – though I think it could be done in principle). It is indeed possible to build infinite containers with fast access by simply avoiding the long chains that lists use in favour of more linked "knots", and... well, we're back to memo-tries there, see?

Comment: For ease, here's Ralf Hinze's paper describing Memo Tries http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.3272

Comment: `memo-trie` is pretty easy. The vast majority of the library is piles upon piles of `HasTrie` instances. If you only looked at one specific type, there would be very little code. About the only non-obvious thing going on is the use of an associated data type in the class, and that's only there because it has to support many types.